Avoid evaluating if-constexpr branch not taken
The following code fails to compile with the error no member named 'foo' in 'B' despite that only being an issue within a context that should be discarded at compile time.
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    int foo() {
        return 1;
    }
};

struct B {
    int bar() {
        return 2;
    }
};

static constexpr bool TEST = false;
using T = std::conditional_t<TEST, A, B>;

int main() {
    T t{};
    if constexpr (TEST) {
        return t.foo();
    } else {
        return t.bar();
    }
}

What can I do to enable code like this? If I were to replace the constexpr with preprocessor macros this would likely work just fine, no?

if constexpr only works in function templates.  main is not a function template

Statements can only be discarded if they're in a dependent context. Put that in a function template taking a type T and it will work.

Dupe: "If constexpr" in C++17 does not work in a non-templated function and Why does the false branch of "if constexpr" get compiled?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if has this to say about your situation:

Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked

This suggests that you can stick it into a template to make it work:
template <typename U=T> int myMain()
{
    U t{};
    if constexpr (TEST) {
        return t.foo();
    } else {
        return t.bar();
    }
}

int main() {
    return myMain();
}

Note: the stuff must actually depend on a template parameter; if you just keep the T t{};, that variable isn't really templated and the compiler will, again, just complain again. So, I had to provide a little workaround -- from the compiler's perspective, I could pass any U, so it has no clue what the t will be, and thus it will work.
cppreference actually explains it as

If a constexpr if statement appears inside a templated entity, and if condition is not value-dependent after instantiation, the discarded statement is not instantiated when the enclosing template is instantiated.

However, their explanation of "value-dependent" is written in some language that seems to use English words, but doesn't convey much in terms of meaning. So, I'll go with my intuitive explanation plus the part "the discarded statement is not instantiated" from the above quote, and go to bed without a headache.

having the behavior differ based on whether or not it relates to a template parameter of a function is unexpected. I'm curious to know why it would ever be desirable to evaluate the branch not taken but regardless, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

@keltek yeah, that hit me too at some point. It's not impossible that this is another concession for compiler makers. In fact, functionally, if constexpr outside of templates almost feels like a normal ìf except that no code is produced even without optimization -- with optimization and a constant condition, one of the branches would have the code removed as well, and we'd also just have "checking"...
